# Override equal method and Bidirectional Relationship

Tags: java, stack-overflow

When check instance is equal with other instance, I get

`java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Because of there are bidirectional relationship, That's why, my `Override equal method` call `equal()` function each other recursively.
Should I remove one check equal condition in `override equal method` of one side? 
What will be better way? Some PG suggest to me to use `EqualsBuilder` of Apache.

OrderItem.java

```
 public class OrderItem {
            private String id;
            private Order order;

            public OrderItem(String id, Order order) {
                this.id = id;
                this.order = order;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setOrder(Order order) {
                this.order = order;
            }

            public Order getOrder() {
                return order;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object object) {
                if (this == object) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(object instanceof OrderItem)) {
                    return false;
                }
                final OrderItem other = (OrderItem)object;
                if (!(id == null ? other.id == null : id.equals(other.id))) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!(order == null ? other.order == null : order.equals(other.order))) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Order.java

```
        public class Order {
            private String id;
            private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;

            public Order(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setOrderItemList(List<OrderItem> orderItemList) {
                this.orderItemList = orderItemList;
            }

            public List<OrderItem> getOrderItemList() {
                return orderItemList;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object object) {
                if (this == object) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(object instanceof Order)) {
                    return false;
                }
                final Order other = (Order)object;
                if (!(id == null ? other.id == null : id.equals(other.id))) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (!(orderItemList == null ? other.orderItemList == null : orderItemList.equals(other.orderItemList))) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Test

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Order order1 = new Order("1");
            List<OrderItem> orderItemList = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
            orderItemList.add(new OrderItem("1", order1));
            orderItemList.add(new OrderItem("2", order1));
            order1.setOrderItemList(orderItemList);


            Order order2 = new Order("1");
            List<OrderItem> orderItemList2 = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
            orderItemList2.add(new OrderItem("1", order2));
            orderItemList2.add(new OrderItem("2", order2));
            order2.setOrderItemList(orderItemList2);

            if(order1.equals(order2)) {
                System.out.println("Equal");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Equal");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does an OrderItem need to know about the Order in which it is contained? Assuming it does - does the fact that it belongs to one order or another change its nature (i.e. could you not say that 2 order items are equal if they have the same ID, regardless of the containing order)?

Comment: if we use JPA onetomany bidirectional, we need to know

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it to use only `id`attribute for equality check. But this is **important**: don't forget to override also the `hashcode()` method if you want your entities behave correctly in Java collections.